# Dojo : animateProperty for "display"

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to animate changes of the CSS "display" property with Dojo and dojo/_base/fx.

Here's my code :

```
function invert_display(id) {
    var element = dom.byId(id),
        currDisplay = style.get(element, 'display'),
        nextDisplay = currDisplay === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
    baseFx.animateProperty({
        node: id,
        properties: {
            display: 'none',
            backgroundColor: '#f00'
        }
    }).play();
}
```

Everything seems to work fine, modules are imported properly (AMD style), variable values are valid and the div background-color turns red but the div doesn't fade out ("display" property set to "none").

Thanks you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The `display` style cannot really be animated, as it doesn't have any intermediate values between `none` and the visible states (`block`, `inline` etc).

To make it fade in/out, you need to animate the `opacity` style (Dojo's base fx actually already has [functions for this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/fx.html#dojo-base-fx-fadeout)). Since you also want to animate the colour, you can for example you can change your function into something like:

```
function invert_display(id) {
    var element = dom.byId(id),
        opacity = style.get(element, 'opacity');

    baseFx.animateProperty({
        node: id,
        properties: {
            opacity: opacity<1 ? 1 : 0,
            backgroundColor: opacity<1 ? '#00f' : '#f00'
        }
    }).play();
}
```

Now, setting the opacity to 0 doesn't remove the element, it just makes it transparent. If you want to elegantly remove it as well, you could perhaps add `height: opacity<1 ? 42 : 0` to the animation as well, making it "minimize" while fading. Alternatively, you can use the `onEnd` and `onBegin` functions to set the `display` style when the animation is finished/beginning (this doesn't always look very elegant though).

Example here: http://jsbin.com/aqigoj/1/edit