# Have invisible forms on a webpage and want to make them visible on button click with DojoToolkit, not sure what's wrong with the code I have

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I'm trying to learn Dojotoolkit and I wanted to make a form pop up on the button click. And from other examples my code looks right to me but there's something I'm missing but I have no idea what.

Any advice and help is appreciated!

```
<button id="slog">Login</button> or <button id="rlog">Register</button>?

<div id="anim8target" style="opacity: 0"> 
<form action="login.jsp" method="POST">
<fieldset><legend>Login</legend>
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
Password: <input type="passwor" name="password"><br><br>
<input type="input" value="Login">
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<div id="anim8target"  style="opacity: 0">
<form action="register.jsp" method="POST">
<fieldset><legend>Register</legend>
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
Display name: <input type="text" name="dname"><br><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
Password: <input type="passwor" name="password"><br><br>
<input type="input" value="Register">
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js" data-
dojo-config="isDebug: 1, async: 1, parseOnLoad: 1"></script>
<script>
require(["dojo/_base/fx", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function

(baseFx, on, dom) {
    var loginButton = dom.byId("slog"),
    registerBUtton = dom.byId("sreg"),
    anim8target = dom.byId("anim8target");
    on(loginButton, "click", function(evt){
        baseFx.animateProperty({
            node: anim8target,
            properties: {
                opacity: 1 }
        }).play();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can have look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638809/dojo-animateproperty-for-display) question as well in addition to @ken answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `visibility` CSS property can't be animated.  It's either `hidden` or `visible`.

If you're trying to do a fade in, there is a [convenience function](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/fx.html#fadein) for that.  In this case, you would want to initialize your styles with `opacity: 0` rather than `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I edited my code to reflect those changes. Still can't seem to figure out how to get them to appear.